# Mac not working correctly after using Wine

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hardware, wine

I have a early 2011 Macbook Pro running El Capitan. I decided to get a steam account and download an old game for the sake of nostalgia. I then realised the game I had downloaded only ran on Windows, so I downloaded Wine from https://www.winehq.org/ to get it running.

I managed to get Steam Windows version running via the Wine app and play the game however now there are issues. Certain buttons on the mac do not work, such as the volume controls for example do not work correctly, with other buttons such as the F1 key for example not working at all.

Has anybody else had this issue and been able to resolve it? I have done some basic troubleshooting steps such as resetting PRAM but has not changed anything.

Cheers,

M.

Comment: If you reboot and not play the game, is everything working okay or do you still have the issues you've mentioned? If you boot to safe mode, is everything working okay or do you still have the issues you've mentioned? Have a look at: [Use safe mode to isolate issues with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201262)

Comment: Hi, issue has actually been resolved now. Problem was in fact that F1, F2 etc were set as standard function keys, unchecked this and keys work normally again. Thanks for your response. Cheers, M.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that F1, F2 etc were checked as standard function keys under keyboard in system preferences. Unchecked these and now everything is working OK.